# SQL Datatrigger - no errors thrown but not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatrigger

I have 2 Database tables - let's call them table A and table B. When a new row is inserted in A, a new row has to be inserted in B (schemas are not identical). This is my test version of a datatrigger:

```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTrigger]
  ON [dbo].[TABLE_A]
  AFTER UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [172.11.22.33].[My_DB].[dbo].[TABLE_B] (column1, column2, column3,  column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10, column11, column12, column13, column14)
  VALUES(value1, value2, value3,  value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10, value11, value12, value13, value14)
  END
  GO
```

When I execute the datatrigger it doesn't throw any errors, so it's correct syntaxwise. However, when I save something in TABLE_A, it throws a System.Data.UpdateException and won't let me save anything until I delete the lines starting with INSERT and VALUES from the datatrigger. INSERT statement is correct, because when I execute it not in a datatrigger but as a separate Query, it works perfectly. What could be the problem?

Comment: You've created an AFTER UPDATE trigger, but you are talking about some action AFTER INSERT.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem.